# Simulating Boolean Return Values in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I know that the closest one can get to a boolean data type in SQL Server 2005 is the `BIT` data type. However, SQL Server obviously works continously with boolean values (after all, it can handle comparisons). That being, is there any way one can "simulate" a boolean return value from an UDF? For example, I would like to be able to make a `CHECK` constraint using the syntax

`(...) CHECK (dbo.FunctionReturningTrue())`

instead of

`(...) CHECK (dbo.FunctionReturningBit() = 1)`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MS SQL Server, no.
`Boolean` is not a directly usable data type. You must compare the value to something.